# How to apply this certain VBA code to all worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I need to protect all my worksheets in a workbook but still enabling the collapsing/extending of groups. I tried searching online for a VBA code, and arrived with this one:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    With Worksheets("Monitoring")
        .Protect Password:="", userinterfaceonly:=True
        .EnableOutlining = True
        .EnableAutoFilter = True
        If .FilterMode Then
           .ShowAllData
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

However, this only applies to a single worksheet labeled "Monitoring". This is also inserted in the "ThisWorkbook" file in the VBA window. I have around 50 worksheets, and am thinking that a universal code may do the trick. However, after trying to google it out, none of the results I tried worked.

May I ask for your help regarding this matter. Thanks and good day! :) :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to add is a `For Each` loop through all of the `Worksheets` :

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    With ws
        .Protect Password:="", userinterfaceonly:=True
        .EnableOutlining = True
        .EnableAutoFilter = True
        If .FilterMode Then
           .ShowAllData
        End If
    End With
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried running this one, but it always gives the message "The password you supplied is not correct. Verify that the CAPS LOCK key is off and be sure to use the correct capitalization." However, when applying the original code to a single worksheet, it doesn't give this message and works perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected some were already protected, and there are indeed some. I'll try running the code again after all are unprotected. Thanks!

Comment: @J.Mapz after the un-protection, is it working now as you intended ?

Comment: yep it did. Thanks! So it was a loop after all. :)

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        With sh
            .Protect Password:="", userinterfaceonly:=True
            .EnableOutlining = True
            .EnableAutoFilter = True
            If .FilterMode Then
               .ShowAllData
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```